# create function in another database dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to create function on every database while I'm on master,
I'm  using cursors

```
DECLARE c_db_names CURSOR FOR
      SELECT name 
      FROM sys.databases
       WHERE name NOT IN('master','model','msdb','tempdb','ReportServer$SQLEXPRESS','ReportServer$SQLEXPRESSTempDB') 
      OPEN c_db_names
      FETCH next from c_db_names INTO @db_name

      WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
      BEGIN

      set @sql = 'Create function...'

set @UseAndExecStatment = 'use ' + @db_name + ' exec sp_executesql '+@sql

        exec Sp_executeSql @UseAndExecStatment
        FETCH next from c_db_names INTO @db_name
      END
      CLOSE c_db_names
      DEALLOCATE c_db_names
```

the problem is that its not working, it says:
"CREATE FUNCTION' must be the first statement in a query batch"

Any ideas?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: add the word "GO" after your USE DB command.

Comment: try and separate your statements into two batches using GO command. Put it Before 'Create function'.

Comment: tryind it b4, "Incorrect syntax near 'go'."
it dosent work with go.

Comment: The problem is that the error rise no matter where if put the go,
"'CREATE FUNCTION' must be the first statement in a query batch."

Comment: Its a good question because as JiggsJedi has shown, we CAN execute commands in different databases in one cursor statement. I didn't think it possible until now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use db..sp_executesql instead:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max), @db_name nvarchar(max), @sql2 nvarchar(max)

DECLARE c_db_names CURSOR FOR
      SELECT name 
      FROM sys.databases
       WHERE name NOT IN('master','model','msdb','tempdb','ReportServer$SQLEXPRESS','ReportServer$SQLEXPRESSTempDB') 
       and name ='reports'
      OPEN c_db_names
      FETCH next from c_db_names INTO @db_name

      WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
      BEGIN

      set @sql2 = 'create procedure ...'
      set @sql = 'exec '+@db_name+'..sp_executesql N''' + @sql2+''''

        print @sql
        --exec(@sql)
        FETCH next from c_db_names INTO @db_name
      END
      CLOSE c_db_names
      DEALLOCATE c_db_names
```

Comment: You cannot use 'GO' inside sp_executeSql

Comment: I did not know this.  Thank you, I have updated sample to account for that.

Comment: Your solution working fine. But in one case when there is '-' in my DB name like "My-DB" then it is throwing error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'DB'.

Answer (score 0):

define the database in "create" query

try

```
DECLARE c_db_names CURSOR FOR
      SELECT name 
      FROM sys.databases
       WHERE name NOT IN('master','model','msdb','tempdb','ReportServer$SQLEXPRESS','ReportServer$SQLEXPRESSTempDB') 
      OPEN c_db_names
      FETCH next from c_db_names INTO @db_name

      WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
      BEGIN

        set @sql = 'Create function '+@db_name+'dbo.functionName ......'

        exec Sp_executeSql @sql
        FETCH next from c_db_names INTO @db_name
      END
      CLOSE c_db_names
      DEALLOCATE c_db_names
```

see:

**set @sql = 'Create function '+@db_name+'dbo.functionName ......'**

Answer (score 0):

done :)

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max), @db_name nvarchar(max), @sql2 nvarchar(max)
declare @sp_executesql nvarchar (max)
DECLARE c_db_names CURSOR FOR
      SELECT name 
      FROM sys.databases
       WHERE name NOT IN('master','model','msdb','tempdb','ReportServer$SQLEXPRESS','ReportServer$SQLEXPRESSTempDB') 
       --and name ='reports'
      OPEN c_db_names
      FETCH next from c_db_names INTO @db_name

      WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
      BEGIN


      set @sql2 = N'
CREATE FUNCTION [String_Turn_Month]  (@d char(6))
RETURNS char(6)
AS
BEGIN 
DECLARE @#DSTR char(6)
IF @D=''''000000''''
set @#dstr=''''000000''''
IF substring(@d,3,4)<1800
RETURN(@D)
IF substring(@d,3,4)>1800
set @#dstr=cast(substring(@d,3,4)+substring(@d,1,2) as char(6))
RETURN(@#DSTR)
END'
  --  set @sql = 'exec '+@db_name+'..sp_executesql N''' + @sql2+''''

  set @sp_executesql = 'exec ' + @db_name + '..sp_executeSQL N''' + @sql2 + ''''
  PRINT @sp_executesql
    EXEC sp_executeSQL   @sp_executesql

        print '------------'
        print '------------'
        print '------------'

     --   exec(@sql)
        FETCH next from c_db_names INTO @db_name
      END
      CLOSE c_db_names
      DEALLOCATE c_db_names
```